# How to import images dynamically using Webpack in Electron JS (Vue JS)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, import, electron

I tried a lot of ways to import pngs dynamically but it keeps saying..

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './SGSkysTheLimit.png'
    at webpackContextResolve (eval at ./src/renderer/assets/img/square sync recursive ^\.\/.*\.png$ (renderer.js:5418), <anonymous>:374:11)
    at webpackContext (eval at ./src/renderer/assets/img/square sync recursive ^\.\/.*\.png$ (renderer.js:5418), <anonymous>:369:11)
    at VueComponent._callee2$ (TestComponent.vue?87f2:114)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:296)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:114)
    at step (asyncToGenerator.js?0f75:17)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?0f75:35)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (_export.js?63b6:36)
```

I tried solutions like these

```
Example 1:
<img :src="fileName(game.key_name)">

Example 2:
<img :src="require(`../assets/img/square/${game.key_name}.png`)">
```

```
async fileName(filename) {
  // Not working
  const image = await require(`../assets/img/square/${filename}.png`)
  return image

  // Not working
  return import(`../assets/img/square/${filename}.png`)

  // Not working
  let image = `../assets/img/square/${filename}.png`
  return require(image)
            
  // Not working
  return require(`../assets/img/square/${image}`)

  // Not working
  var images = require.context('../assets/img/square/', false, /\.png$/)
  return images('./' + filename + ".png")

  // Working
  return require("../assets/img/square/SGJellyfishFlow.png")
  // but the problem is I need image is dynamically imported
}
```

[image]

App\src\renderer\assets\img\square\SGSkysTheLimit.png

I tried a lot of search on stackoverflow and github but all of them not fix my problem.

Comment: Could you include the paths for the image and the file trying to include it?

Comment: question updated